# How to mirror two striped hdds with zfs?

Tags: raid, zfs, mirroring

I had two 1G+1G disks striped together. (filenames used for example)

```
config:

    NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    xxx                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      /media/user/storage/x1    ONLINE       0     0     0
      /media/user/storage/x5    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Now I bought 2G hdd.

Is this possible to mirror that stripe to get something like this:

```
config:

    NAME                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    xxx                               ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror
        stripe
          /media/user/storage/1G-1    ONLINE       0     0     0
          /media/user/storage/1G-2    ONLINE       0     0     0
        /media/user/storage/2G-1      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Why do you want this setup?

Comment: @ewwhite Wanna to migrate from two disks into one. I may create new ZFS pool and do rsync but first wanna try native method if they are

Comment: If your goal is simply migration, how about going with the zfs send | zfs receive approach?

Comment: @airhuff Good idea, thank you. I have migrated. May I put this two empty disk in mirror as described above? or I should split 2G by two sliced and put each slice into mirror with empty disk?

Comment: With your current disks, if you value your data, I would mirror the 1G disks and use the 2G for "internal" backups via `zfs send`.  That is a quick backup that won't slow down your system (at least from a disk io perspective) when you later move the backups to an external drive or something.  As far as performance, remember that ZFS does "striped" reads on a mirror configuration, and only takes a small performance hit on writes.  Depends on your use case, but you usually read a lot more than you write ;)